# How to split a XArray dataArray?

Tags: python, split, geojson, python-xarray

I have downloaded heavy spatial data. I want to clip those data with a geojson file for shapes. But those spatial data are too heavy to be handled by my computer. Is there a way to split this dataArray in n pieces and treat each piece one after the other?
Or is there a way to clip huge dataArrays without MemoryError?

```py
data.load()
```

[image: xarray DAtaArray with dims (band: 1, y: 100000, x: 100000)]

Comment: yep! don't call `.load()`. Instead, chunk the array, e.g. on read with `xr.open_dataset(..., chunks={'x': 1000, 'y': 1000})`, then work with the array using dask. See the docs on [working with dask](https://examples.dask.org/xarray.html) for more info.

Comment: see also [`regionmask`](https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/) which does what you seem to be asking about and works with dask arrays